# Html <nav> vs <ul> for nav bars

Tags: css, html

Which better conforms to the new HTML5 standard to use for a navigation bar on a web page, the new HTML5 nav tag  or using the ul tag with css?

I would think the latter because more browsers are able to use HTML 4.01 than HTML 5, although in recent years that gap may have closed a bit.

```
 <!--HTML5 Way -->
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <body>
      <nav>
         <a href="/html/">HTML</a> |
         <a href="/css/">CSS</a> |
         <a href="/js/">JavaScript</a> |
         <a href="/jquery/">jQuery</a>
     </nav>

   </body>
 </html>

 /*CSS way*/
 #topmenudiv ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
 }

 #topmenudiv li{
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:0.9em;
    border-right: 1px solid #990000;
    height: 100%;
    padding:10px 20px 12px 20px;
    float: left;
 }


 <body>
        <div id="topmenudiv">
            <ul>
                <li>News</li>
                <li>Sports</li>
                <li>Weather</li>
                <li>iPlayer</li>
                <li>TV</li>
                <li>Radio</li>
                <li>More...</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</body>
```

Can anyone give a definitive answer on this? Through your experiences which would be better to use for a website?

Comment: Go ahead and use `<nav>` unless you're supporting some prehistoric browser, or IE8. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly both work just as well. As of now, nobody has really implemented anything in any web browser that takes advantage of the new semantic tags in HTML5, and a lot of the tags are both vague and ambiguous and a lot of people are unsure of how to use them. The spec doesn't really clear much up. Tags like `<article>` and `<section>` can be used in a lot of different ways (should I put sections within divs for visual purposes? should the `<h#>` tag for the heading of a particular section go inside it or just above it? why do some websites show articles alongside sections in diagrams but state that the article is the primary content of a website?)

For now, I'm doing my best to simply replace `<div>`s with more logical semantic tags wherever it makes sense. In your case, I would keep using a `<ul>` for your links and put the list inside a `<nav>` tag instead of inside a `<div>` tag.

It's important to keep in mind that in practice, all the HTML5 semantic tags behave exactly the same as and are meant to replace the standard meaningless `<div>`. **Non HTML5 browsers will treat `<nav>` and other new elements like `<div>`s.**

Example for you (taken directly from the [Mozilla Developer Network page for the nav element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav)):

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Further reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document
- http://html5doctor.com/lets-talk-about-semantics/
- http://www.anthonycalzadilla.com/2010/08/html5-section-aside-header-nav-footer-elements-not-as-obvious-as-they-sound/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav

**READ THE THIRD LINK**
I highly recommend reading through all three articles, but the third link is, in my opinion, a must read. It does a great job of pointing out all the problems I discussed above and will perhaps clarify things for you (or at least point out the lack of clarity). The fourth link specifically outlines how to use the  element.

Comment: And “HTML5 browsers” treat `<nav>` like `<link>`. There is no magic in `<nav>` unless someone writes code that gives it some magic.

Answer (score 2):

There is not going to be an absolute answer here, but this is how I would approach the issue:

As a developer, I always try to use the latest technology (after it has been publicly tested and approved), whether that extends to particular syntax of how I code a block of HTML, or how I choose a framework for a project. That being said, I would encorage you to use a `<nav>` element for your main navigation. You are correct, `<nav>` is an HTML5 element, that will only be recognized by browsers that support HTML5 (which is all major ones at this point, going back a few major versions).

So...what about older browsers that don't support HTML5, and even better what about older browsers such as IE < 9, that don't even render HTML5 elements on the page correctly?? It is for these cases I recommend using an [HTML5 enabling script](https://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script) - which uses a "hack" or as I like to say "IE fix" to make sure even these browsers (yep IE6+) render your shiny new HTML5 elements correctly.

[This article](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/semantics.html#unknown-elements) does a wonderful job summarizing unknown HTML5 elements, and the fixes to get around older browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

1. **[semantic css](http://css-tricks.com/semantic-class-names/)**
2. **[HTML5 nav](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/navhttp://)**

my answer refers above links. Many opinion is about the browser compatibility. Further more, I think the user experience is more important. This **user experience** is in particular for audio-visual disabled people. Their device can help them to read the page easily when you use **nav**.

Answer (score 0):

You must put the `<ul>` into the `<nav>`.

Example:

```html
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Contact us</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: There is no must! :)